# Sort actual QMap by key

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qtcore, qmap

I have `QMap<QString, MyClass*>`. I need to sort it by key using natural comparison. 
I do:

```
std::map<QString, MyClass*> map = c.toStdMap();
std::sort(map.begin(), map.end(), strnatcmp1<std::pair<QString, MyClass*>>);
```

However, this does not even compile. And even if it did, as far as I understand, it would sort a *copy* of my original `QMap`.

Is there any way to sort my `QMap` by key with the function for comparison keys provided?

Comment: Why would you do this?! A QMap is a red-black tree, it's already sorted by key.

Comment: If the key is QString, it is sorted  lexically ( 1 10 11 2 3 4 ), but I need natural comparison ( 1 2 3 4 10 11 ).

Comment: In that case, why not use an int as the key?

Comment: Because QString is already used everywhere in the project. It wasn't me who wrote this software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several appoaches that you could take:

- Store the keys as integers after converting `QString` to an integer.
- You can use the compare class for std::map [as per the example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/):
- You can try to use specialize [this template function](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/a3cb057c3d5c9ed2c12fb7542065c3d667be38b7:src/corelib/tools/qmap.h#L63) that QMap uses for the comparison.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QDebug>
#include <map>


struct str_num_compare {
  bool operator() (const QString& lhs, const QString& rhs) const
  {return lhs.toInt()<rhs.toInt();}
};

int main()
{
    QStringList stringList{"1", "10", "11", "2", "3", "4"};

    QMap<int, QString> map;
    foreach (const QString &string, stringList)
        map.insert(string.toInt(), string);
    qDebug() << "Integer key approach:" << map;

    std::map<QString, QString, str_num_compare> std_map;
    foreach (const QString &string, stringList)
        std_map[string] = string;
    qDebug() << "QString key approach with std::map:";
    for (auto item : std_map)
        qDebug() << item.first;


    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
Integer key approach: QMap((1, "1")(2, "2")(3, "3")(4, "4")(10, "10")(11, "11"))
QString key approach:
"1"
"2"
"3"
"4"
"10"
"11"
```